# Why Like returns empty whereas = returns result?

Tags: mysql, sql-like

I have a table specialization(id, name) where name is a varchar with indexing on it. When I run query using like I get empty result, whereas if I use = in query it gives me exact result.

My queries are as follows:

```
select * from specialization where name like 'Anesthesiology';
```

This return Empty set

```
select * from specialization where name = 'Anesthesiology';
```

This returns one result set.

Why is this happening?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the answer is on this page:  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/case-sensitivity.html.  This is complicated and depends on collations and possibly extended characters in your strings.

Comment: Did you try it directly in mysql? It should works, if the name exactly `'Anesthesiology'`. I've just tried it on my own database, and it works.

Comment: Yes, it works. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/75b875/1

Comment: @lolka_bolka: Yes just found that in db it was stored as 'Anesthesiology '. My bad. Thanks for giving clue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect there are trailing spaces in the 'Anesthesiology' value in your database so like will fail but strangely, = will find it.

Comment: Thanks. It infact is right. It was 'Anesthesiology ' in db. But then why does = finds it correctly?

Comment: = ignores the whitespace in mysql. I've started using postgresql because of these joys of mysql :)